# Last three column values in postgresql going as null while sending them through php laravel

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

```
if ($dataRaw['type'] == "CheckIn") {
$res = $this->fetchLocations($dataRaw['entityid'], 'checkins');
\App\CheckIn::create([
    'type'                   => $dataRaw['type'],
    'reason'                 => $dataRaw['checkinreason'],
    'device_id'              => $ssid,
    'deviceuniqueidentifier' => $dataRaw['deviceuniqueidentifier'],
    'date_time'              => gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", hexdec(substr($dataRaw['entityid'], 0, 8))),
    'entityid'               => $dataRaw['entityid'],
    'latitude'               => $res['Latitude'],
    'longitude'              => $res['Longitude'],
    'address'                => $res['Address'],
    'queue'                  => $k,
]);
}

if ($dataRaw['type'] == "Event") {
$res = $this->fetchLocations($dataRaw['entityid'], 'events');
\App\Events::create([
    'type'                   => $dataRaw['type'],
    'reason'                 => $dataRaw['eventtype'],
    'device_id'              => $ssid,
    'deviceuniqueidentifier' => $dataRaw['deviceuniqueidentifier'],
    'date_time'              => gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", hexdec(substr($dataRaw['entityid'], 0, 8))),
    'entityid'               => $dataRaw['entityid'],
    'queue'                  => $k,
    'latitude'               => $res['Latitude'],
    'longitude'              => $res['Longitude'],
    'address'                => $res['Address'],
]);
}
```

This is where my query is made it is sending null values for last three columns latitude longitude and Address. I have also checked the values coming up in $res array they are also printing fine. there is also no error in the posted logs.

Events.php

```
  <?php
  namespace App;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
  class Events extends Model
 {
     protected $table = 'events';
     protected $fillable = ['type', 'reason', 'is_processed', 
    'device_id', 
    'deviceuniqueidentifier', 'date_time', 'entityid', 'queue', 
    'is_deleted'];
  }
```

Comment: do you add those columns to the **fillable** array in the **Event** model?

Comment: Sorry but i didn't understand your question i am not much familiar with Laravel. But the problem i am facing is that all other values are getting saved except the last three. Last three are going as null

Comment: I edit your post to show more clearly please accept it. also, paste the content of **App/Events.php** file

Comment: also, paste the result of `dd($res)`

Comment: Events.php added i think i need to add those in to this file. Thanks for mentioning !!! I am gonna try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add those columns to fillable array like this:

```
protected $fillable = [
'type',
'reason',
'is_processed',
'device_id',
'deviceuniqueidentifier',
'date_time',
'entityid',
'queue',
'is_deleted',

// follwing lines missing
'latitude',
'longitude',
'address',
];
```

**Hint:** You can use **$cast** to let column value retrun as true or false:

```
protected $casts = [
  'is_processed' => 'boolean',
  'is_deleted' => 'boolean'
];
```